# Writing "getInitialState" using ES6 standards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble updating this code to use ECMAScript6 standards. I used to set `getInitialState` on a plain javascript object and pass it to the `React.createClass` API. I want to understand how can I rewrite the snippet below to use the recommended ES6 syntax for React components.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            tabList: tabList,
            currentTab: 1
        };
    }

    changeTab: function(tab) {
        this.setState({ currentTab: tab.id });
    }

    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <Tabs currentTab={this.state.currentTab} tabList={this.state.tabList} changeTab={this.changeTab}/>
                <Content currentTab={this.state.currentTab} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6 it is recommended to use the following syntax:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Initialise your state here.
    this.state = {
      tabList: tabList,
      currentTab: 1
    };

    // Bind your functions to this, avoiding scoping issues.
    this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this);
  }

  // Use function property syntax
  changeTab(tab) {
    this.setState({ 
      currentTab: tab.id 
    });
  }

  render() {
    // deconstruct your state.
    const { currentTab, tabList } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
          <Tabs currentTab={currentTab} tabList={tabList} changeTab={this.changeTab}/>
          <Content currentTab={currentTab} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 class style, you just assign initial state to `this.state` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tabList: tabList,
        currentTab: 1
    };
 }
```

See [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes):

> Instead of providing a separate getInitialState method, you set up your own state property in the constructor.

Also note that, when using ES6 classes, handlers like `changeTab` [won't be autobound](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding), so you need to bind them explicitly, ideally in the constructor (`this.changeTab = this.changeTab.bind(this)`).